# SQL Authentication for Transfer class

Tags: c#, .net, sql, authentication, transfer

I am having issues transfering database with data using Transfer Class. It works fine without transfering data. With data I get

> ERROR: error code= -1071636471 description = SSIS Error code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>
> An OLE DB error has occured. Error code 0x800040005/ An oledb record is avialable.     Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: 2Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows
>   authentication"

The class has a property `transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;` which when set to false, is not using intergrated security. I have tried setting various properties to no avail.

Connection string which connects fine in every other instance i use it.

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connections.dbConnection_HTOUTER()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                Database dbMaster = server.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dbMaster")];
                Database dbProduction = server.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dbProduction")];
                Transfer transfer = new Transfer(dbMaster);

                string login = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("login");
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");

                transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
                transfer.CopyAllUsers = true;
                transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
                transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;

                transfer.DestinationServer = server.Name;
                transfer.DestinationDatabase = dbProduction.Name;
                transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
                transfer.DestinationPassword = password;
                transfer.DestinationLogin = login;

                transfer.CopyAllRules = true;
                transfer.CopyAllRoles = true;

                //transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;

                transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;
                transfer.CopySchema = true;
                transfer.CopyData = true;
                transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = false;
                transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
                transfer.Options.Indexes = true;

                transfer.TransferData();


            }
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17676149/220230

Comment: Jed I, did you ever get anywhere with this?  I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set, the user, password of origin and destination server manually.

**This will work:**

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilderOriginDatabase = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ORIGIN"].ConnectionString);

ServerConnection originConnection = new ServerConnection(connectionBuilderOriginDatabase.DataSource);
originConnection.LoginSecure = false;//very important
originConnection.Login = connectionBuilderOriginDatabase.UserID;
originConnection.Password = connectionBuilderOriginDatabase.Password;

Server server = new Server(originConnection);
Database dbMaster = server.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dbMaster")];
Database dbProduction = server.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dbProduction")];
Transfer transfer = new Transfer(dbMaster);

string login = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("login");
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");

transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
transfer.CopyAllUsers = true;
transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;

//Here you are configuring the destination server
transfer.DestinationServer = server.Name;
transfer.DestinationDatabase = dbProduction.Name;
transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
transfer.DestinationPassword = password;
transfer.DestinationLogin = login;

transfer.CopyAllRules = true;
transfer.CopyAllRoles = true;

//transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;

transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;
transfer.CopySchema = true;
transfer.CopyData = true;
transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = false;
transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
transfer.Options.Indexes = true;
```